# Unity Xcode Compile not Signed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying everything and going to be crazy. I'm currently working on **unity/vuforia augmented reality** project at work. I made a sample for presentation on *android* there is no problem. But when I copy project to *mac* and try to compile unity compiles with succees but *xcode* keeps failing. I says unsigned but signed it how can i fix this. Any idea guys? Pretty please :/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your project window, under the Target named something like `Unity`, you should find `Singing` under the tab `general`. Here your can pick one of your imported team from the Apple developer portal. If you don't have one (imported) yet, you can use the automatic singing option to let xCode do it for you.

[image: xCode signing]

Comment: As I said I already did it.That's why I couldn't figure it out.